# Use of "as" with verbs?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, comparisons

Would you say:

> I don't know anybody who has as much energy as John.

or

> I don't know anybody who has as much energy as John does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one.

> I don't know anybody who has as much energy as John.

As John what? It is kind of implied, but it could be:

> I don't know anybody who has as much energy as John wasted.
>
> I don't know anybody who has as much energy as John when he is playing sports.

You need to say does.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those implied words in English:
I don't know anybody who has as much energy as John [does] or as John.
Both are correct. 
This is similar to: Do you want to play tennis today?
Yes, I want to [play tennis] but I'm busy all day.